# how to use one class with many elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

for some reasons i have somthing like this in my html code

id = 1

```
                     <li class="anyclass" ></li>
                            <li   class="firstclasname + id" ></li>
                            <li   class="scondclasname + id" ></li>
                            <li   class="thirdclasname + id ></li>
                            <li   class="forthclasname + id" ></li>
                            <li   class="fifthclasname + id" ></li>
                      </ul>
```

id = 2

```
 <li class="anyclass" ></li>
                            <li   class="firstclasname + id" ></li>
                            <li   class="scondclasname + id" ></li>
                            <li   class="thirdclasname + id ></li>
                            <li   class="forthclasname + id" ></li>
                            <li   class="fifthclasname + id" ></li>
                      </ul>
```

can i make just one css file for this code contain something like this :

```
.every first calss name + what ever id  {
```

`background-image: url('/image/facebook.png');`
 `background-repeat: no-repeat;`
 `background-size: auto;`
 `background-position: -277px -446px;`
 `}`

Comment: .every first calss name #what ever id  {
background-image: url('/image/facebook.png');  background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-size: auto;  background-position: -277px -446px;  }

Comment: if each class is going to have the same styles, why not add a common class "background" to all li's and add the styles to that class. This will eliminate redundancy!

Comment: What is `firstclasname + id` supposed to mean?

Comment: it mean firstclasname1

Comment: Looks as though this is being generated by scripting. These look like variables rather than class names.

Comment: yes by php i add the id to the class name

Answer (score 0):

For cases like this I like to use two selectors -- a common one, relevant to all the items, and a specific one to identify a single item.

An example use would be something like this:

```
<ul class="contact-list">
    <li class="item item-1">Contact 1</li>
    <li class="item item-2">Contact 2</li>
    <li class="item item-3">Contact 3</li>
</ul>
```

In CSS you can then target the list itself, all the items or one specific item.

**Edit**

Apologies, I skimmed your question and missed the part about id=1 and id=2. There are a few different options depending on how many IDs there will be and whether or not this will be known.

For a short list of known ID's you could just target the individual items as I mentioned. If there are an unknown number of IDs (or the IDs themselves are unknown) you may consider using the `nth-child` selector.

This depends entirely on the effect you're trying to achieve, which isn't detailed in your question, but some commonly used (in the context of my example markup above) are as follows:

- `.contact-list:nth-child(odd)` applies to every odd element, i.e. 1st, 3rd, 5th
- `.contact-list:nth-child(even)` applies to every even element, i.e. 2nd, 4th, 6th
- `.contact-list:nth-child(1)` applies only to the first element
- `.contact-list:nth-child(4n+4)` applies to every fourth element

And so on. Most common requirements have been done a thousand times before and can be found with a quick google search along the lines of "CSS every second element".

Comment: there is no relation with first , second , third its just random class name just change it with alex+id , jhon+id

Comment: @user7369177 In that case all I can suggest is that you make it as easy as possible to target through multiple CSS classes, i.e. each item in a set should have something like `class="thing thing-1 property-1", "property-2" etc, where "thing-1" relates to id=1. Ultimately there has to be some predictable format else you cannot possibly hope to target it. CSS is incredibly flexible, so perhaps if it isn't working out you need to change your approach. If you describe your desired _outcome_ in your question you will get a more appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to try nth-child of CSS3 property.

```
ul.yourClass li.firstclasname:nth-child(2){ 
   background:url('/image/facebook.png') -277px -446px no-repeat;
   background-size:auto;
```

}

Comment: am sorry but it has no relation with first or second its just random class names you can change this with alex+id  , john +id

Answer (score 0):

You can use starts with `[attr^=value]` attribute selector.

```css
li[class^="firstclasname"] {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="anyclass"></li>
  <li class="firstclasname1"></li>
  <li class="scondclasname1"></li>
  <li class="thirdclasname1"></li>
  <li class="forthclasname1"></li>
  <li class="fifthclasname1"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="anyclass"></li>
  <li class="firstclasname2"></li>
  <li class="scondclasname2"></li>
  <li class="thirdclasname2"></li>
  <li class="forthclasname2"></li>
  <li class="fifthclasname2"></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: can we use this in css page  and with out the li

Comment: You can try just this `[class^="firstclasname"]`.